# JQuery Mobile Multipage feature is not working with ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use simple multipage feature of jquery mobile, but its not working with my ASP.Net MVC 3 test.cshtml page. Below is the source of the page. Can anyone help me with this?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "TestPage For Multiple Page";
Layout = "";   
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        some content <a href="#linkdiv">Test</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="linkdiv">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Testing
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding target = "_self" attribute to the <a> tag of the calling page, resolved the issue. If you are using multipage in PageB, then make sure the @Html.ActionLink("PageB") of PageA has target = "_self" set.